# How to use IntegerQ on list?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

```
t1 ={0, 1, 2, Log[6]/Log[2], 3, Log[12]/Log[2], 4, Log[24]/Log[2]}
```

I want to get the `Position` of the Integers. I can do it by

```
Flatten[Position[Length /@ t1, 0]]
```

to get the result `{1,2,3,5,7}`. How would I use `IntegerQ` here to get the same result?

Comment: Use `Position[t1, <pattern>, 1]` and find some way to use `IntegerQ` in a pattern ([spoiler](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

```
IntegerQ/@t1
```

gives a vector consisting if Trues and Falses. So you want the Positions of all those that have True:

```
Flatten@Position[IntegerQ /@ t1, True]
{1,2,3,5,7}
```

Comment: Also `Flatten@Position[t1, _Integer, 1]`